# Why does the bootstrap close icon button have space at the top?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a close button with the bootstrap close icon, code as follows:

```
<button type="button" className="close bg-primary">
  &times;
</button>
```

However the button appears to have space at the top:

[image]

Any ideas what this space is and how I can remove it?

Comment: this is the nature of the font

Comment: there is no space in the bootstrap X icon https://icons.getbootstrap.com/icons/x/

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
```

Try out this one.It will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf00d;</i>
```

Also Check out this link.
https://www.w3schools.com/icons/tryit.asp?filename=tryicons_fa-close